# Split 1 DataFrame column containing Float64 values into several

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where I want to split the float64 list values into separate columns.
The current DataFrame looks like:

```
                                    0
Fp1   [0.17447164115148173, 0.06726957143085581, 0.17298492547895647, 0.10928149060730677]
F3    [0.15979351009681514, 0.11017144893549853, 0.16213662211559293, 0.10816689203332136]...
```

I would like to split the one column into 4 so:

```
        0                       1                   2                    3
Fp1   [0.17447164115148173] [0.06726957143085581] [0.17298492547895647] [0.10928149060730677]
F3    [0.15979351009681514] [0.11017144893549853] [0.16213662211559293] [0.10816689203332136]...
```

I have found things close to solving the problem (like using pd.str.split() etc but they do not work because the data format in the columns at the moment is float64.

Any help appreciated, thankyou!

Comment: `df[0].astype(str).str.split(',',expand=True)` ??

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
df[0].apply(pd.Series)
```

or

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]), axis=1)
```